# у меня тут проблема с логикой получение сообщение

Tags: reactjs, websocket

Когда я отправляю либо получаю сообщение я делаю запрос на websocket и мне нужно продумать саму логику получение потому что каждый раз делать запросы на сервер это не очень мне важны любые идеи

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Зачем по сокету делать постоянные запросы? Сам сервер должен отправить сообщение клиенту по событию.